# Accessing the structure using a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have declared a structure "node" having a member variable 'm' and then defined two variables as below

```
struct node t, *p;
```

Later in the program I assigned the address of `t` to `p`:

```
p = &t;
```

To access the member variable I need to use `p->m`.

But I wanted to use the `*` operator, but writing it `*p.m` gives error. Why is it so ?

Comment: ummm...what is `a`?

Comment: use `(*p).memberVariable` .   `.` has precedence 1, `*` precedence 3.   http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us *why* you want to use the dereference operator? Using it you will be writing two more characters every time you do it, and it might not be so clear for readers of the code.

Comment: Using  `(*p).member` instead of `p->member` is highly discouraged.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just wanted to learn, I am new to C and asked out of curiosity

Comment: `p->t.m` does not make sense (at least what I can understand in this example). Use `p->m`. Read up pointer to structures to understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this you have to see the precedence of the operators.

The precedence of `.` operator is higher than `*` operator.

Writing it like `*p.m` makes the compiler think that it is `*(p.m)`.

You will have to use `(*p).m`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The expression `*p.memberVariable` is equal to `*(p.memberVariable)`. I.e. it tries to dereference `p.memberVariable` as a pointer, not `p`. This will give you a compiler error because `p` is a pointer to a structure and you can use the dot-operator to select structure members.

You need to explicitly tell the compiler to dereference the pointer `p` using parentheses: `(*p).memberVariable`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence, `*p.memberVariable` will not work. Do `(*p).memberVariable` or `p->memberVariable`